# List all databases in MongoDB through Realm functions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

Is there a way to list all the databases from realm functions? I need the list to be queryable from another service, but this should not have access to the whole DB. Only a list of all DBs would be perfect, but the service in Mongo Realm can only do standard queries and aggregations and nothing else.

Is there any known way around this issue? Or at least does anyone know why there is this limitation?

In my use case, each DB is a Customer. Each customer gets its own DB so it can be easily deleted, created, etc. independently. I need a list of all customers, but I don't want to have a duplicate "customer storage" as this is the only action I cannot do with Realm.